# Textbox not checking if null or not

Tags: c#, string, button, textbox, isnullorempty

In my form application there is a textbox, and two buttons, I need to start a process, and in the textbox whenever it is empty I need the button below it to disable. I have tried the google'd help, i.e :

```
public void buttonenableordisable()
{
   if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
   {
       button1.Enabled = false;
   }
   else
   {
       button1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

But it just disables the button, upon adding text to the textbox, the button doesn't enable, it stays greyed out. I have also tried,

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox1.Text)) 
{
    button1.Enabled = false; // <<== No double-quotes around false
} 
else 
{
    // Don't forget to re-enable the button
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

But that doesn't work either. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `buttonenableordisable()` being called?

Comment: From which event handler you call this code?

Comment: @DanWilson calling it in the form() where :                                              public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            buttonenableordisable();


        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind to the [`TextChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the textbox and call your method. It can also be simplified.

As it is, you are only calling your method once when the form loads.

```
public void buttonenableordisable()
{
    button1.Enabled = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text);
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    buttonenableordisable();
}
```

Comment: if i call the buttonenableordisable(); method in textchanged, the button is not greyed out if the textbox is empty.

Comment: Nevermind i called it in the form aswell and it works, thanks.